# Finding number of solutions when condition is given.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Q - Find number of solutions when it is given that Re(z²) = 0 and |z| = a $\sqrt{2}$ , where z is a complex number and a>0.

First I assumed $z = x + iy$ and then squared it and equated the real part to $0$.
I don't know how to approach after that. 
Please guide.

Comment: One solution is $z=1+i$. Can you generalize this to more solutions?

Consider when $a=b=2^{n}$ for some natural number $n$.

Comment: @RobertThingum how did you get this answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then

1. $\Re(z^2)=0$, implies $r^2\cos(2\theta)=0$.
2. Also $|z|=a\sqrt{2}$ implies $r=a\sqrt{2} \neq 0$.

From these two, we get $\cos(2\theta)=0$. This implies $2\theta=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$ or $\theta=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{4}$.

Thus $z=a\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{4}}$, where $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Now you can count the *distinct* solutions out of these as:
\begin{align*}
z& =a\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}=a\left(1+i\right)\\
z&=a\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}=a\left(-1+i\right)\\
z&=a\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{5\pi}{4}}=a\left(-1-i\right)\\
z&=a\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{7\pi}{4}}=a\left(1-i\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: So, this means that there can only be 4 solutions to this question, right? Because from 9pi/4 answers will repeat. Isn't it?

Comment: @KaustuvSawarn Yes, only 4 distinct solutions.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I didn't approached with the exponential form. Isn't there any way this question can be solved assuming $z= a+ ib$ ? I mean I understood how to solve this assuming exponential form, but I'm just curious than can this be solved using $z = a+ ib$ form?

Comment: @KaustuvSawarn It can be solved with $z=a+ib$ approach as well. Look at Robert Thingum's approach. However as you can see it is a bit longer and arguably less elegant. Usually, whenever powers of complex numbers are involved, the polar form ($r,\theta$) form is helpful.

Comment: Yes, oh I didn't notice the edit on his answer. I'm sorry.

Comment: Thankyou so much for solving the answer with this approach. I upvoted your answer but it says "votes cast by voters less than 15 reputation doesn't show publicly." I guess it's because I'm new on this platform

Comment: @KaustuvSawarn Thanks!! I am happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

Let $z=a+bi$ where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

The condition $Re(z^{2})=0$ means that $a^{2}=b^{2}$ because,

$$z^{2}=(a+bi)^{2}=a^{2}+2abi-b^{2}=(a^{2}+b^{2})+2abi$$

Then $Re(z^{2})=0$ implies $a^{2}-b^{2}=0$ which gives us that $a^{2}=b^{2}$.
Now the condition that $|z|=\alpha\sqrt{2}$ for some $\alpha>0$ means, by definition that

$$|z|=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}=\alpha\sqrt{2}$$

Squaring both sides will give us that

$$a^{2}+b^{2}=\alpha^{2}2$$

We could just say that $a^{2}+b^{2}=2\beta$ for some $\beta>0$. Note then that we have a system of two linear equations with two unkowns ($a^{2}$ and $b^{2}$).

$$a^{2}-b^{2}=0$$
$$a^{2}+b^{2}=\beta2$$

Of course $\beta$ depends on $a$ and $b$, but that doesn't make things very difficult. Setting $a=b=1$ and $\beta=1$ yields one solution. Setting $a=b=2^{n}$ for some natural number $n$ yields another solution with $\beta=2^{n}$.

Using some basic linear algebra you can show that for every $\beta>0$ there is some choice of $a$ and $b$ that will solve the system.

Choosing $\beta=1$ we get that choosing $a=\pm1$ and $b=\pm$ yields a solution. In general for a specific $\beta=\alpha^{2}$ where $\alpha>0$ we have (taking into account Anurag A's solution) that any of $a=\pm\alpha$ and $b=\pm\alpha$ will suffice. To see this note that

$$a^{2}-b^{2}=(\pm\alpha)^{2}-(\pm\alpha)^{2}=\alpha^{2}-\alpha^{2}=0$$
$$a^{2}+b^{2}=(\pm\alpha)^{2}+(\pm\alpha)^{2}=\alpha^{2}+\alpha^{2}=2\alpha^{2}=2\beta$$

So, as Anurag A showed, for a given $\alpha>0$ there are exactly four solutions.

$$\alpha+\alpha i$$
$$\alpha-\alpha i$$
$$-\alpha+\alpha i$$
$$-\alpha-\alpha i$$

Comment: How does it tell you the number of distinct solutions?

Comment: Does this mean that there is an infinite number of solutions of this question? I mean there can be infinite number of 'a' and 'b'

Comment: @KaustuvSawarn for a given $a$, the number of distinct solutions is finite. See my answer.

Comment: No. The question is for general $alpha$, it just says $alpha$ is greater than zero in the question

Comment: But the answer is given as 4.

Comment: Right. But you are given a single $\alpha$ to start. It isn't asking for the number of solutions to all equations of that type. Also, I realized that you could well deduce that there are exactly four solutions using the linear system I wrote up.

Comment: I will edit my answer to reflect how the four solutions are found.

Comment: Thankyou Robert, I learned how to approach the question both ways, one by yours and one by Anurag's.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably assuming that $z = a+ib$;

So from here

$z^2=(a+ib)^2=a^2+2ib-b^2=a^2-b^2+i(2b)$

-Put it this way so you can see $Re(z^2)=a^2-b^2=0$

And $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\alpha\sqrt2$

And now we know:

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\alpha\sqrt2$$
$$a^2-b^2=0$$

Since it's given that $\alpha>0$, you can square both sides of the first equation without changing anything:

$a^2+b^2=2\alpha^2$

$a^2-b^2=0$

Comment: I've reached till here but I don't understand what to do after getting this.

Comment: Since it's said that $a>0$, you can just square both sides of the first equation to get $a^2+b^2=2a^2$